# label element always enabled

Tags: html, label, disabled-control

i use disabled attribute for disable/enable elements.but `label` element has problem with this attribute ,when set this attribute to `disabled` do not work.
See bellow code & link

```
<label disabled="disabled" for="ch1">Click to Me</label>
<button disabled="disabled"  >Cannot Click to Me</button>
<input type="checkbox"  id="ch1" />
```

http://jsbin.com/wagoku/1/

Comment: This is because `<label>` elements don't have a `disabled` property, only `<input />`, and other interactive elements, (except `<a>`) have that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable a label per se. Disable the form control it is associated with instead.

```
<label for="ch1">Click to Me</label>
<input type="checkbox" disabled id="ch1">
```

http://jsbin.com/pojojike/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the label use css something like

```
 .disabled {
   color: darkgrey;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

And to add the class to your element:

```
$('#click').addClass('disabled');
```